# Drag and Drop works only in one direction

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with the Drag and Drop API in Javascript.
I have two areas one called *widgets* and another called *selection*. Now I want to be able to drag and drop the widgets from one area. This already works but only when i drag a widget to the selection panel.

When I want to drag it back to the *widgets* panel. It does not work. According to my debugging the **dragstart** event is never called. All other events work, only this event seems not to be fired.

But I can't find any reason why this event is never fired.

This is the code of the **dragstart** event handler:

`widget.on('dragstart', function(e){

```
        this.style.opacity = '0.4';

        console.log('started');
        dragSrcEl = this;
        console.log(dragSrcEl);

        console.log(this.outerHTML);
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);
    });
```

`

I have made a jsFiddle, where you can find the whole code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3FLaS/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself:

The jQuery selector `$('.widget')` does not get notified when an element changes his "position".

You have to use an other selector like `document`, when you use the on method on this is works as expected and the event is fired at each dragstart.

`$(document).on('dragstart', '.widget', function(e){
this.style.opacity = '0.4';

```
    console.log('started');
    dragSrcEl = this;
    console.log(dragSrcEl);

    console.log(this.outerHTML);
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.outerHTML);
});
```

`